# Adding Scroll Bar to Sharepoint Multi Line Texts Column not allow complete text in a cell to show

Tags: list, sharepoint, scrollbar

I am not a developer, but I am trying to develop a function to see multi line texts in a sharepoint list with a scroll bar because it sometimes is so long that it makes the height of the column too high to look orgnized. I used the following JSOn script, and it indeed added a scroll bar but when I click the arrow to the top, I cannot see the first line of values.  How can I make changes in my script to view entire values by scrolling up and down?

[image]

{
"$schema":"http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
"elmType":"div",
"style":{
"font-weight":"bold",
"font-family":"Trebuchet MS",
"font-size":"13px",
"font-size-adjust":"0.58",
"overflow-y":"auto",
"max-height":"50px"
},
"txtContent":"@currentField"
}

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by adding one more script:     "display": "block"

Thank you!